# Why does an exact match on a name return a useless set of venues?

Tags: foursquare

This doesn't make much sense to me, and I'm hoping someone can shed some light on what's going on here and how I work around it.

If I query like this:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=37.77%2C-122.41&radius=15000&intent=browse&oauth_token=xxx&limit=20&query=pi%20ba

I get a list of about 15 items, including the item I'm searching for (pi bar).  However, if I search for the exact match name:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=37.77%2C-122.41&radius=15000&intent=browse&oauth_token=xxx&limit=20&query=pi%20bar

I just get back the blanket list of venues within this area (mostly BART stops, etc.)

Is it expected that I should have to shave the last character off of user entered queries to get results back, or is this just a messed up venue name that I've been debugging with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this may help, but I've discovered placing an "and" between words in your query can produce more accurate results:

Searching for Chili's Bar & Grill

The first query has extraneous results:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=34.07527923583984,-84.29469299316406&radius=5000&query=chili's bar grill&oauth_token=xxx&v=20111205

The second is much more accurate (although I've removed the ampersand: &)

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=34.07527923583984,-84.29469299316406&radius=5000&query=chili's and bar and grill&oauth_token=xxx&v=20111205

Answer (score 1):

There's a known issue with quality of bigram matches in foursquare venue searches -- your query term includes a very popular word ("bar") which skews the results. The search team is working on quality improvements for these sorts of queries.

Comment: Is it documented anywhere what words are affected by this?  It's easy enough for me to change any 'bar' query terms to just 'ba', or modify any other words like this that need to be tweaked.

Comment: I don't recommend working around the issue: hopefully this will be resolved soon.

Comment: OK, one last question.  Is that list of 20 venues that get returned when it doesn't make a match static?  I don't want to display anything when nothing matches, so I need to filter those results from being returned to the client.  Is there any way to just enable this browse API to only return things that match?

Comment: Those are substring matches, they're not static across all queries.