# Alternative to intent=match?

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to match existing data to Foursquare Venues. I've tried matching about 100,000 records using intent=match and 30% of them don't return results. Now, sometimes these venues are actually missing, but sometimes the search just isn't finding results that would be obvious to a human. For example:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?intent=match&ll=40.075800000000001,-80.698800000000006&query=19%20TH%20HOLE

That returns no results. However, if I search for "19TH HOLE" I do get a result.

I could just add all these non-matches to Foursquare, but it seems that I'd end up creating a whole lot of duplicates... and I don't want to abuse the system. We're trying to make Foursquare our Venues database, and we can't go and process 300,000 records without matches by hand, either.

I'm open to suggestions on what else I can do.

Comment: This really feels like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207279/why-does-an-exact-match-on-a-name-return-a-useless-set-of-venues

You did not really explain what your process is or why you search with a query, so it is a bit hard to give suggestion on what you should be doing..

Comment: I actually read that thread. My problem is a bit different... I've got like 1,000,000 places to match. Usually when the name matches, intent=match works great. I'm asking about when the name *doesn't* match, and intent=match doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can "relax" the search strictness by specifying `intent=checkin` or `intent=browse` and using your own criteria to determine if the top result is the one you're looking for.

Comment: But then my real question is... after I put my best-faith effort into finding all the matches via an automated process, is it then ok to just add the rest of the locations via another automated process? The documentation here seems to say so: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/mapping.html

Comment: Yes, if you have the authority (ownership of the intellectual property) to submit those venues, then that is the recommended option. Alternatively, you can get in contact with the foursquare business development team to provide the information as a bulk import. See https://foursquare.com/business/merchants/claiming for details about adding (/claiming, which you wouldn't be doing) a large number of venues

Comment: That's what I needed to know, thanks. I'm going to get an updated copy of the data, and submit the missing venues.